# QGIS 3.18 error on install python modules for SCP

Tags: pyqgis, matplotlib, scp, scipy

I downloaded the QGIS 3.18 version for Mac. (College assignment). I need to also download the SCP plugin, however when I do that, I get errors "when importing scipy and matplotlib" dependencies.

I have installed in my mac both python 3.9 and 3.11.
I have set `python` as an alias for `python3`, same with `pip`, and thus installed both scipy and matplotlib as libraries located in:
`/Users/silphonix/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages`.

I know this libraries do not exist inside the QGIS environment as when I try to do an import, the python console returns syntax errors. The errors returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/code.py`.

So here we have a mismatch, I have everything installed in 3.11 however looks like the QGIS is using 3.9. I tried to set a `PYTHONPATH` to the site-packages folder of 3.11, and also change the PATH
from:

- `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:`

to:

- `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:`

Any tips on how can I solve this? I found a lot of solutions but for Windows, and the ones I found for Mac, didn't work.

Edit

I was able to install scipy with the commands

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'scipy'])

import scipy

but when i try to import matplotlib with the same method i get
"ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Applications/QGIS3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/matplotlib/**init**.py)" however with the finder, im unable to find that file... any tips?

screens

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you try `import pip; pip.main(['install', 'scipy'])` from the QGIS Python console?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca when i use that commands, i get a new instance of QGIS with a lot of errors of type "Unknown data source: "X" is not a valid or recognized data source, where X is different files concerning the lib. 

And then after i close that instance of QGIS with errors, on the python console of the first instance, i get :

pip.main(['install', 'matplotlib'])
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.

Comment: To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.6.2.tar.gz (35.8 MB)
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /private/var/folders/5v/1ks0kmt171n7y0b5g0b77dh00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-kxv887ob
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Applications/QGIS3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: If i try to use any of those commands, i get "Syntax error"

Comment: All the Warning is true, this is not the recommended way to use pip, but it is just a warning. I can't understand what you say about the new instance of QGIS opened. QGIS must not launch a instance with this command, and must not try to load X files (about which lib? pip? scipy?). About the Syntax Error, I can expect an error form pip not having a main attribute, but a syntax error? Verify your syntax because I can't see it. Also, in your edit, you are installing and importing the modules at the same time. Install matplotlib, don't import it. If the installation was ok, then you can import it.

Comment: first, i had problem installing the packages, because the python console threw errors. I was able to solve that, i get no errors on instalations, however when i try to import matplotlib i get that error there

Comment: Does the SCP plugin work now?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca hi, no, as i mentioned i get that "_c_internal_utils_" error when importing matplotlib. However installing it does not return errors.